# numpy - is Z[[1, 2],[1]] completely same with Z[(1,2),(1)]?

Tags: numpy, matrix-indexing

As per the answer of [numpy - why Z[(0,2)] is view but Z[(0, 2), (0)] is copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484964/numpy-why-z0-2-is-view-but-z0-2-0-is-copy), now understood **comma** can trigger [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) which is also warned in the document.

> Warning The definition of advanced indexing means that ***x[(1,2,3),] is
> fundamentally different than x[(1,2,3)]***. The latter is equivalent to
> x[1,2,3] which will trigger basic selection while the former will
> trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this occurs.

Once advance indexing is **triggered with comma**, is tuple indexing the same with array indexing? If so, why there are two ways to do the same?

If they are not, please help understand why and the rational/decision behind to decipher the numpy behaviors.

```
Z = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
print("Z is \n{}\n".format(Z))

print("Z[[1, 2],[1]] is \n{} Is view {}\n__array_interface__ {}\n".format(
    Z[
        [1,2],
        [1]
    ],
    Z[[1,2],[1]].base is not None,
    Z[[1,2],[1]].__array_interface__
))

# Comparison with tuple indexing
print("Z[(1,2),(1)] is \n{} Is view {}\n__array_interface__ {}\n".format(
    Z[
        (1,2),
        (1)
    ],
    Z[(1,2),(1)].base is not None,
    Z[(1,2),(1)].__array_interface__
))
---
Z is 
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

Z[[1, 2],[1]] is 
[5 9] Is view False
__array_interface__ {'data': (94194177532720, False), 'strides': None, 'descr': [('', '<i8')], 'typestr': '<i8', 'shape': (2,), 'version': 3}

Z[(1,2),(1)] is 
[5 9] Is view False
__array_interface__ {'data': (94194177118656, False), 'strides': None, 'descr': [('', '<i8')], 'typestr': '<i8', 'shape': (2,), 'version': 3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Z[[1, 2],[1]]
```

Indexes the first dimension with a list [1,2], and the second with list [1].  Actually indexes with `np.array([1,2])` broadcasted against `np.array([1])`.  So it's the 2 elements from rows 1 and 2, and column 1.

```
Z[(1,2),(1)]
```

is the same.  Both have a comma creating an outer tuple which is passed to the `__getitem__` method.  `np.array((1,2))` is the same as `np.array([1,2])`.  `(1)` is not a tuple, it's just `1` (no comma).  Again, rows 1 and 2, column 1.

`Z[(x,y)]` is the same as `Z[x,y]`; it's the comma that makes the tuple, not the ().

```
x[(1,2,3),]
```

The comma creates a tuple `((1,2,3),)`, and in effect tells `x.__getitem__` that we are selecting from the first dimension of `x`.  `x[[1,2,3],]` and `x[np.array([1,2,3]),]` are the same.

```
x[(1,2,3)]
```

is equivalent to `x[1,2,3]`, providing scalar indices for 3 dimensions of `x`.